# Is "I'll when" proper form?

Tags: grammar, phrases, adverbs, sentence, contractions

A friend of mine keeps using a contraction like this and I keep correcting him by asking "I'll what?". He doesn't get it though, and no matter how much I try to explain it doesn't seem to sink in.

For example, I tried explaining that in most cases you can't use a contraction (more specifically ones that refer to a person(s) like I'll, they'll, he'll and so on) right before who/what/where/when/how/why, that he should use "I will" instead of "I'll" unless he's asking a question; "I'll when?" makes sense, "I'll when it's finished" doesn't.

So, just to clarify, does "I'll when" work when it's not a question?

How can I better explain it to him? I'm having a hard time and I seem to be making a mess of it rather than helping.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are asking.  Can you please add a couple of the "I'll when?" question forms as examples that make sense, plus at least one more non-question example that doesn't?  Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I didn't express my request properly. My question was: Is "I'll when" grammatically correct? Meaning, is it proper form to use a contraction before an adverb with nothing in between them like "I'll when"?

Comment: @SehraFarron: Again, please give examples of full sentences that you believe are grammatical/ungrammatical, or want to ask about. Not sentence fragments. It should be easy enough to do, right? It will help ground the discussion in something concrete. (As an aside, I note that you used "I'll what" in the first sentence.)

Comment: "I'll when it is done." I didn't think examples would have been required as I thought that perhaps this was incorrect grammar in general regardless of sentence.

Comment: The "I'll what?" wasn't an example by the way, it's a question I ask him whenever he uses "I'll when" in a sentence, something I do to bring his incorrect grammar to his attention. Yes, "I'll what?" is a question and is correct use of the contraction before a pronoun. My question is, is it grammatically correct to use a contraction before the adverbs when, how, what and why with nothing in between them? I should think the sentence it is used in is irrelevant as the sentence is not in question, simply the use of those two words, no?

Answer (score 6):

The contraction works when *will* is being used to express the simple future. For instance:

> I'll eat it later.
>
> I will eat it later.

The verb *will* can also be used to express intent or willingness, rather than just the future.

> Will you do it?
>
> I will when I have time.

In this case, you can't use the contraction, and *both* the sentences below are grammatically incorrect:

> I'll when I have time.
>
> I'll when?

You can remember this easily by looking for the emphasis in the sentence - *eat* or *will*. The sentence doesn't work if there's no emphasis. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shall_and_will) provides a comprehensive overview of sentences using *shall* and *will*.

I've been unable to find sources comparing your construction to the correct one, but this doesn't surprise me as it's not a common mistake.

The only time this makes any sense as a question is when you haven't heard or want to question what the other person is saying, and you can use *what*, but not *when*. Even then I suspect this is a colloquialism rather than correct grammar.

> You'll lend me $200, won't you?
>
> I'll what?

Comment: Do you have any sources? I can't find a mention of this in the Wikipedia article you linked.

Comment: Try this one if you want more: http://www.annies-annex.com/auxiliary_verbs.htm - afraid I have no formal references. You can also google for "contraction" and "auxiliary verb" since that's what "will" is in this case.

Comment: Not "more"; I just want any sources at all. :-) BTW I can't find the rule in the link you just gave either. Can you point to a specific section (either in the Wikipedia article or the above link) which pertains to "I'll when"?

Comment: Search for "contraction" in the articles. The only reference I could find to contraction was with "will" used as an auxiliary verb; it's not contracted in any other context. The confusion suffered by commenters who couldn't even see that you'd already posted a complete sentence should act as evidence enough for this. If you doubt it, try it out on native English speakers and watch what happens!

Comment: So to clarify, you're pointing to sources which say that "will" is contracted when used as an auxiliary verb, to conclude (based on absence) that it cannot be contracted in other contexts? You don't have any sources that actually talk about "I'll when" itself, right? Could you make this clearer in your answer?

Comment: I draw my conclusion based on being a fairly well-educated English speaker, not on sources alone :) Edited accordingly anyway.

Comment: Yes, I also find the construction very unusual, and have never seen it before. But the aim is to find some reliable linguistic sources, instead of depending on our intuition and experience alone. :-)

Comment: If only there were enough resources to cope with everyone's imaginary grammar constructions!

Comment: You are exactly right, it is a colloquialism. The only reason *I'll what* is accepted is because the main verb *do* is implied here, and so omitted. The sentence really is saying "I'll **do** what?" or fully expanded - *"I will do what?"* But you can't *do* a *when* so *"I'll when..."* is missing its main verb entirely (*will* is a modal so it must precede a main verb). I can't link my source because I found it in my hardbound copy of *A Writer's Reference: Fourth Edition* under the *Special problems with verbs: a) helping and main verbs* section.